# I have youtube channel, how do I convert requests in comments to income?

Tags: business-plan

This is my youtube channel it basically about coding -

[YT Channel Link](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCteo8bQnfFFFZoQADQx-fRw)

Few people request work or quires regarding how can I use this opportunity to generate revenue as my YT channel does not generate revenue still via ads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a whole market on top of monetizing youtube channels. Mostly:

### advertisement

You make money by running ads, either from youtube or any company that wants you to talk about their brand. vpns, mental health apps, online learning sites, etc etc.

Youtube's ads are great because you don't need to chase and negotiate with companies, but they don't bring that much money

### merchandising

People like your work, so you setup a shop to sell generic stuff to your audience. Usually t-shirts with memes related to your content, with your logo or any kind of product that people by to show support.

### patreons

People that like your content will give you money in exchange for relevance or special benefits, there are dozens of sites you can setup to ask people for a monthly fee to help support you making videos.
Some people just want to help, some people like getting something in return, like an exclusive community, or private zoom chats where people can ask questions and get more attention from you. That kind of stuff.

### courses

The way online tutorials work is:

- introductory videos make tons of views
- advanced videos don't

So, if you create a 'learn python in 10 minutes' or 'build a simple android app', there are many people that will watch that because not much knowledge is required and people are generally curious

However, videos like 'troubleshooting memory leak in enterprise applications' won't get that many views because most people don't have that knowledge or don't need to know that. It's valuable knowledge, just not something that will appeal to the general public.

So the strategy here is:

- make a lot of introductory free content, so people learn the technology from you and get used to your way of teaching
- then make a paid course and tell everyone: 'hey, if you like my introductory content, I made this advanced course for the ones that want more!'

The idea being:

- people will learn the basic stuff for free
- then they'll get a job or a freelance and make some money
- then they can afford to pay you to learn advanced stuff

### freelancing

you can advertise yourself as a worker, but I don't recommend that, that creates a very weird relationship. will people be your fans/viewers or your clients?

### apps

you can also build utility apps based on the requests and publish them online or in the app stores with ads, or just sell the code in places like https://codecanyon.net/?auto_signin=true

Answer (score 1):

To generate income from comments, you need to be creative. There's lots of very successful developer teachers on YouTube. See what they're doing on YouTube. Look for CTAs (calls to action) See what they offer on their websites. Many people create YouTube videos to generate traffic to other websites. In turn, creating a steady stream of visitors to eCommerce sites with relative products such as monthly memberships, or Udemy/personal courses.

It's not common to generate income directly from comments. The goal is to guide users to another source that will generate revenue.

Before you can begin making AUTOMATED money on YouTube however, you need to meet the subscriber and hours watched minimums of 1,000 and 4,000 respectively. At that point you can monetize your videos. Monetizing your videos allow relevant ads to display which generate $$ contingent upon audience interaction. Read more up on this here: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/72851?hl=en